# Logic of breakoutline in Makefile depedencies

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I'm reading a C library. And i met a strange makefile types with multi depedencies on multi lines, such as:

```
phuonga: 
    echo ">>>>>>>>>>>phuong a"
.PHONY : phuonga

phuongb: 
    echo ">>>>>>>>>>>phuong b"
.PHONY : phuongb
phuongc: 
    echo ">>>>>>>>>>>phuong c"
.PHONY : phuongc

phuong: phuonga
phuong: phuongb
phuong: phuongc
    echo ">>>>>> Runned phuong"
```

But when i run by make phuong, this result is:

```
>>>>>>>>>>>phuong c
>>>>>>>>>>>phuong a
>>>>>>>>>>>phuong b
>>>>>> Runned phuong
```

It's not appear a,b,c or c,b,a. The order is c,a,b
Why it follows this order? I don't understand that logic.

Thank a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first prerequisites are *always* the ones in the prerequisite list of the rule containing the recipe.  After that the prerequisites are added in the order that they were seen in the makefile.  So for:

```
phuong: phuonga
phuong: phuongb
phuong: phuongc
        echo ">>>>>> Runned phuong"
```

the line containing the recipe lists `phuongc` as the prerequisite so that always comes first.  After that the first prerequisite seen is `phuonga` so that comes next, followed by `phuongb`.

If you write the rules like this:

```
phuong: phuonga
phuong: phuongb
phuong: phuongc
phuong:
        echo ">>>>>> Runned phuong"
```

where none of the prerequisites are listed in the rule containing the recipe, then they'll come out in the order they are defined in the makefile (`phuonga`, `phuongb`, `phuongc`).